# How to load a converted pre-trained keras model to Tensorflow.js using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflowjs-converter

I have pre-trained keras models that I have conveter using TensorflowJs Converter. I'm trying to load them in this following script

(index.js)

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');

require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
global.fetch = require('node-fetch')

const model = tf.loadLayersModel(
     'model/model.json');
```

I'm getting the following error when I execute `node index.js`

```
(node:28543) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request for model/decoder-model/model.json failed due to error: TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
```

and

```
(node:28543) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:28543) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have also tried this

```
const model = tf.loadLayersModel(
     'https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/tfjs/iris_v1/model.json');
```

But here I get

```
(node:28772) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Found more than one (2) load handlers for URL 'https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/tfjs/iris_v1/model.json'
```

### System Information

Node v10.15.3 and
TensorflowJs v1.0.1

Comment: Package.json dependencies `  "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^1.0.1",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^1.0.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.3.0"
  }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
```

With

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
```

And remove the line

```
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
```

Then, if you are loading a model from the local file system, add 'file://' to the beginning of the argument you give to loadLayersModel().

And it should work

Answer (score 0):

The first error is clear, it wants an absolute URL (`'/model/model.json'`) but you feed it a relative one ( `'model/model.json'`).

The second error is also rather clear, the error tells you that the former thrown error did not get catched (it's therefore `Unhandled`).

For the last one, please see
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/779
 or https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/622

I think this is because mixing CUDA and non-CUDA things. Check your `packages.json` first.

Comment: I have changed to the absolute URL `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request for /model/decoder-model/model.json failed due to error: TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported`

Comment: @n00b lol ok and then you tried a complete URL right, what did it give you

Comment: I have posted the error in the previous comment. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @n00b no, what is the error when you put in a full URL, beginning with http(s).